# Setup apache2 with a custom docroot in vagrant using chef

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I am a complete newbie to vagrant and chef. As a first project I decided to simply setup an apache2 and point the docroot to the shared folder.

That seems to require the execution of the "web_app" goal of the apache2 recipe of chef and giving the docroot as a variable. However I am not able to figure out how to do this in the context of vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that you use the latest version of Apache cookbook

Second, when writing new cookbook, declare dependency on apache2 cookbook in metadata.rb

```
depends "apache2"
```

Third, use in your cookbook something like this:

include_recipe "apache2"

```
web_app "testrail" do
    server_name "myproject.com"
    server_aliases ["myproject.com"]
    docroot "/var/www/customroot"
    cookbook "apache2"
end
```